# javascript objects - how to bind to "this"

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope, bind

```
App.Order = {
    oForm : $('#order-form'),

    expertMode :  false,

    expertModeData : null,

    init : function() {
            $('#toggle-expert-mode').on('click', function() {
                this.switchMode();
            });
    }
}
```

How do i bind `this` inside the click event handler. Also is this the right way to add an event listener, i mean inside the init method?

Doing `App.Order.switchMode()` does not make sense as what happens if i change the object name?

Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling I think that the question you answered uses a different design pattern.. but helps understand, thanks

Comment: I didn't use any design pattern. I tried to come with the simplest use case possible (maybe I didn't succeed). The point is that it's the same problem and solved by the answer given there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i **bind `this`** inside the click event handler.

Literally as you said. You `bind(this)`:

```
App.Order = {
    // ...
    init : function() {
        $('#toggle-expert-mode').on('click', function() {
            this.switchMode();
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying `this.switchMode().bind(this)`

Comment: BTW now when the `this` refers to the object how to i get a reference to the original `this` `#toggle-expert-mode` in this case? Currently i have to do `e.target || e.srcElement`